# vscode git commit +50 carácteres

Tags: git, vscode

Alguien ha encontrado como hacer commit en el plugin de VSCODE con más de 50 carácteres?

Estoy buscando por foros / videos pero no encuentro como hacerlo.

Gracias

Comment: En el comentario? Siempre puedes bajar al terminal para hacerlo. Ahí no hay límite de longitud (aunque hay ciertas reglas no escritas... y que ciertamente git no te fuerza a cumplir de ninguna manera). Una primera linea con el resumen (50 caracteres suena razonable.... pero puedes escribir mas de ser necesario), luego una línea vacía y luego todos los detalles que se requiera en las lineas subsiguientes.

Comment: VSCode no te pone ningún limite en realidad. Sólo te advierte cuando has escrito más de 50, porque ese es el convenio en git. La primera línea del mensaje de commit no debería tener más de 50 caracteres. El resto de líneas del mensaje pueden llegar a 70 creo recordar, y puedes poner tantas como quieras. Pero la primera línea debería ser muy concisa, pues es lo que se mostrará en las versiones abreviadas del commit (por ejemplo en la vista en forma de grafo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que estoy leyendo (no uso vscode..) desde 2018 añadieron `git.InputValidationLength` para quitar el límite.

Las opciones son:

```
git.inputValidation
git.InputValidationLength
git.InputValidationSubjectLength
```

Comment: Mil gracias @nax al poder buscar estas entradas lo he conseguido. Mil gracias.